# How do I do two MYSQLI queries in one page, what is the best method

Tags: php, mysqli, while-loop

All right. I'm learning about the mysqli API. I've got two files. One that connects to my database, and one that runs the query. Everything works. However, I want to run two queries in a single page. How can I do this? What is a good method to do this? Would the best way be to include my db connect once, then run both queries, and then close my connection to my db once ending it all together? Is that how most people do it?

db.php

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("..", "..", "..", "..");

/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}
```

query.php

```
include 'db.php';

$sql = "SELECT id, row1 FROM test ORDER by id DESC";

$query = $mysqli->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error());
$row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($query);

if ($row_cnt  > 0) {

    while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row["id"] . $row["row1"];
    }

    $result->free();
}

$mysqli->close($mysqli);
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.data-seek.php

Comment: Does mysqli_stmt_data_seek work like a while loop though? It's important for me to do a while loop because it's like an if statement.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php
Is an option depending on what you want to achieve

Alternatively, you said

> The second query is from the same table but it'll use a * to get all rows.

Ignore me if your code is just an example, but two consecutive select queries from the same table is 'often' not needed, you're getting "id" and "row1" from the *. So you could have one query that gets * in the first place.

Comment: All right. So if I do that how can I run two while loops from it?

Comment: If you're doing only one query and getting * (everything), don't you only need one while loop, as you have selected everything?

Comment: No. I am going to have two main queries. There will be two while loops that each display different rows from the db. One while loop will display all rows where the other loop will display only one row. Each loop will display their content differently. There are two tables that I will be querying which is why I asked my original question. I mostly need to know how to have two queries in one page.

Comment: In your original post you stated same table (as er my previous quote). Can you confirm? As otherwise my trying help you streamline is impossible and you likely need two queries.

Comment: Two tables. I am / was getting off on something else. I'd like to know how to query from two different tables on the same page.

Comment: ok. Did you see my previous link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php. Then you can display your one row and all rows separately

Comment: Multiquery does everything all together though right? it hits the server twice and does all of the queires together and can be taxing if there are a lot of results though right? Isn't it better to handle each query separate? Multiquery is especially heavy when dealing with loops which I will be doing. There is no simple way to execute two different queries?

Comment: "isn't it better to handle each query separate" now were getting into a different area of discussion, and specifics of your setup and requirements would be needed to answer best performance. ie are your DB and scripts on the same box? If not then you consider memory versus network depending on how many queries we're talking about, how quick the network/switches etc is between DB box and scripts box... etc etc. have a read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11120706/is-mysqlimulti-query-more-efficient-than-several-single-queries

Comment: solved it. I was using the wrong variable to free my results. Look at its name. it wasn $result it was $query